# Serilog: restrictedToMinimumLevel using LevelSwitches

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-5, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am using Serilog in a .Net 5 application, and I am configuring it loading the configuration from `appsettings.{env}.json`.

In this file I want to specify a different minimum logging level for each sink, and I would like to control it with a `LevelSwitch` so that I don't need to restart my application only for changing this. To achieve this, I know that `restrictedToMinimumLevel` can be specified for each sink, but I cannot find an example where it is controlled by a switch. It seems it can only be a string with the logging level, since when I tried to bind it to a switch I got this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.'
```

Am I missing something? How can I set the minimum logging level for each sink to be easily changed at runtime without restarting my application?

These are my settings:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "LevelSwitches": {
      "$baseSwitch": "Verbose",
      "$consoleSwitch": "Warning"
    },
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "ControlledBy": "$baseSwitch"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          //"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",   ---> this works
          //"restrictedToMinimumLevel": {            ---> this is what I need, but doesn't work
          //  "ControlledBy": "$consoleSwitch"
          //},
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp} [{Level:u3}] [{LogSource}]: {Message} {Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log.txt"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am open also to other solutions. Thank you.

Comment: because `LogEventLevel` expects string

Comment: @viveknuna ok, but then how can I update the minimum log level at runtime? I am open to other solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the level switch reference should not have the `$` prefix. The `$` prefix is only for referencing the level switch declared

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "LevelSwitches": { "consoleSwitch": "Verbose" }, <<<< No $ prefix
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args": {
                    "levelSwitch": "$consoleSwitch" <<<<<< $ prefix
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, the name of the argument for the level switch has to match what's declared in the extension method for the sink. [In the case of the Console sink, it's called `levelSwitch`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/v4.0.0/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/ConsoleLoggerConfigurationExtensions.cs#L60).

Comment: thank you for your answer, using `levelSwitch` it works as expected. One question: I think that setting the minimum log level and updating it at runtime is some basic stuff that should be somehow available in all the sinks (but maybe this is my idea): why isn't this standardized somehow, to have a common syntax? Is there a reason?

Comment: and for the `$` prefix, I copied the usage from some examples found online, and I can say it works both with and without. Is there a preferred/recommended way to handle them?

Comment: Sinks are developed by different developers and it's up to them to follow a standard naming convention. Not something Serilog can enforce...

Comment: The `$` prefix implies a reference to an existing name, so should be used only when your goal is to tell Serilog that you're referencing an existing name